# audio.PlayOneShot doesn't work in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want  my game to play sound when a player collides with coin, but the sound doesn't play. I don't receive any errors. I attached sound to Audio Source and script in Unity.

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class TriggerCoin : MonoBehaviour
{

    //TODO
    //Counter of collected coins

    public AudioClip coinSound;
    new AudioSource audio;

    void Start()
    {
        audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }


    void Update()
    {

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        GameObject gObj = other.gameObject;

        if (gObj.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                Debug.Log("You picked up coin!");
                audio.PlayOneShot(coinSound, 0.8f);
                Destroy(gameObject);      
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Think this may be because you are destroying the gameobject before the clip has a change to play. Try delaying the destruction, `Destroy(gameObject, 1f); `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the problem below:

`audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();` shows that the `AudioSource` is attached to this script or GameObject this script(`TriggerCoin`) is attached to.

Then you play the audio: `audio.PlayOneShot(coinSound, 0.8f);`

And destroy the GameObject the immediately: `Destroy(gameObject);`.

The destroyed GameObjbect is holding the `AudioSource` too so it will take `AudioSource`  with it to die.

Solution:

Attach the `AudioSource` to an empty GameObject that does **not** destroy. Let's call it *"AudioHolder"* then find it an play the audio.

```
GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("AudioHolder");

AudioSource aud = obj.GetComponent<AudioSource>();

aud.PlayOneShot(coinSound, 0.8f);
```

Note:

Remove the `new AudioSource audio;` and rename audio to something else. It's a good idea to do that.